# Problem executing command from keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, laptop, scripts, pulseaudio

I created some shortcuts to control the audio volume of my laptop, as the default system shortcuts ( <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> / <kbd>F5</kbd>) aren't supported. I downloaded [a script](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=886029#p886029) which allows me to increase/decrease/mute PulseAudio volume.
I created some script which contains the order of increasing/decreasing the volume:
`pulseaudio_volume-decrease.sh`

The problem is, each time it is executed, it creates a "pavolume" file in my home dir that I don't want. Thus, I added "rm pavolume" next to the previous command:
`pulseaudio_volume-decrease.sh; rm pavolume`

When I run it from the terminal, everything is fine; but, strangely, when I call the shortcut (with Gnome 'Keyboard' settings), it fails, telling me "Error while trying to run (pulseaudio_volume-decrease.sh;rm pavolume) which is linked to the key (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>)".

What have I done wrong?

---

I am running on Ubuntu 2D (Unity) 11.10

Comment: The gnome keyboard settings does not run the command in a shell, hence shell code won't work. Anyway, the script you linked to does not create any files, which suggests your `pulseaudio_volume-decrease.sh` may be the one accidentally creating that file. Could you post that script?

Comment: Here it is: `pulseaudio_volume > pavolume increase`...

Comment: As you can see, I'm a bit lost in all this...

Comment: That runs `pulseaudio_volume increase` and writes the output (if any) to the file `pavolume`, creating the file if it doesn't exist. So if you don't want that file to appear, remove `> pavolume` from that line.

Comment: Okay! I understood. I think it's working now. I was really confused as for writing those scripts.
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @geirha Can you post this as an answer so we can get this question off the unanswered list? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was simply me making a beginner mistake in my script: I had written `pulseaudio_volume > pavolume increase` instead of `pulseaudio_volume increase`.

While the latter would merely call the script `pulseaudio_volume` and its method `increase`, the first would

> [run] pulseaudio_volume increase and write the output (if any) to the file pavolume, creating the file if it doesn't exist.

That's why I had that `pavolume` file created in my home directory.